# Laravel Envoyer - Where to store user uploads

Tags: php, laravel, envoyer.io

Docs basically says I need a `envoyer-root/storage` folder alongside with `envoyer-root/current` and `envoyer-root/releases` and then use a system link to link `envoyer-root/storage` to `envoyer-root/releases/{latest one}/public/storage` in order to read those files.

What nobody seems to explain is, where are the newly uploaded files saved to? By my application, they'd be uploaded to `envoyer-root/releases/{latest one}/public/storage`  but that wont make it accessible for the new releases.

Do I have to create a post-deploy and manually copy all the files from the previous release to the `envoyer-root/storage` folder and THEN linking it?  Am I missing something?

PD: for references, I'm using Envoyer with a non-laravel project, so I need to understand if I have to modify my source code to work with Envoyer (which seems smelly to me but w/e we already paid for it), or if I don't and I'm not seeing something.

Comment: Did you figure this out, what was the solution. The automatically created storage symlinks aren't working for me... Environment File Detected: Linking
Storage Directory Detected: Linking

Comment: Yeah, I just marked the accepted answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the "Linked Folders" (within the Deployment hooks tab) to create a symlink from the currently deployed release to a shared storage folder on the server.

So in your case, you'd want to create a symlink from the currently deployed release to the `envoyer-root/storage`. In Envoyer, the link from/link at is relative to the "PHP project root", which is your currently deployed release, and the to link is relative to the server root, so you'd have:

Create link at: `public/storage` (relative to release path)
To: `storage` (relative to server root)

Symlinks created through the linked folders feature are created on each deployment, so it will always create a symlink for each new release.